# Getting fatal error for msi with AD policy

Tags: active-directory, windows-installer, exe, crossrider, ieaddon

We use Crossrider extension for IE browser. Now we want to deploy that in our hole network using AD policy.But when we download this exe and convert into MSI file, that MSI work fine manually on single m/c, But when we are using AD policy for software deployment it give ***fatal error***.

**Error Information is :**

**AD Group Policy Result :** 
Software Installation failed due to the error listed below.
Fatal error during installation. Additional information may have been logged. Review the Policy Events tab in the console or the application event log for events between 6/6/2016 5:49:28 PM and 6/6/2016 5:49:33 PM.

**Event viewer Error :**
Completed Software Installation Extension Processing in 5297 milliseconds.

System

- Provider

  [ Name]  Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy 
  [ Guid]  {AEA1B4FA-97D1-45F2-A64C-4D69FFFD92C9}

  EventID 7016

  Version 0

  Level 2

  Task 0

  Opcode 2

  Keywords 0x4000000000000000
- TimeCreated

  [ SystemTime]  2016-06-06T12:19:33.320250000Z

  EventRecordID 9929
- Correlation

  [ ActivityID]  {1EB21ABC-B3AD-4656-952A-A3D349535344}
- Execution

  [ ProcessID]  972 
  [ ThreadID]  1244

  Channel Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy/Operational

  Computer CDTCLOUD52.COREQA.LOCAL
- Security

  [ UserID]  S-1-5-18

  - EventData

  CSEElaspedTimeInMilliSeconds 5297 
  ErrorCode 1603 
  CSEExtensionName Software Installation 
  CSEExtensionId {C6DC5466-785A-11D2-84D0-00C04FB169F7}

Any Help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to suggest a timeout in the installation process. I'm guessing this is due to the fact that the installation requires human interaction and/or access to the Internet to complete; hence, the installation times out.

Also, note that Crossrider extensions are designed for regular end-users and may not work in an AD environment.

[**Disclosure**] I am a Crossrider employee

Comment: Thank you @Shlomo for information, You are saying that Crossrider extensions may not work in AD environment. Means you are not sure, It will work or not ??

Comment: I say may, because AD/Corporate environments are often locked down for various reasons and often corporate firewalls limit Internet access. Since Crossrider extensions are Cloud based, these limitations can often cause problems and prevent extensions from installing/working correctly.

Comment: Okay, @Shlomo I understand Thank you.